# linq sum amount_db and amount_cr group by date and nrt_acc and company_name

Tags: linq

I have a table named  nrt_bal_sheet

```
date      |company_name|amount_db|amount_cr|balance|     nrt_acc
11/12/2021  MoneyGram   5000           0    5000         0046D
11/12/2021  MoneyGram   0           2000    7000         0046D
11/12/2021  MoneyGram   0           20000   20000        0046D
12/9/2021   Ria Money   0           15000   15000        0039D
12/11/2021  MoneyGram   10000      857300   857300       0046T
12/11/2021  MoneyGram   1000       85730    914318.61    0046T
12/12/2021  MoneyGram   1000       85730    1000048.61   0046T
```

I want to sum of amount_db and amount_cr and balance group by date, nrt_acc, company_name and for those nrt_acc that has last letter "T" only.

I need the following results

```
date      |company_name   | amount_db |amount_cr |  balance  |  nrt_acc

12/11/2021  MoneyGram          11000      943030    932030.00    0046T

12/12/2021  MoneyGram           1000       85730    1016760.00   0046T
```

Here is the code I have already done.

```cs
nrtBalanceSheet = (
    from n in db.nrt_bal_sheet
    group n by new { n.date, n.nrt_acc, n.company_name } into g
    orderby g.date
    select new ValuePassModel
    {
        advice_issue_date = g.Key.date,
        company_name = g.key.company_name,
        company_code = g.key.nrt_acc,
        debit = g.Sum(n => n.amount_db),
        credit = g.Sum(n => n.amount_cr),
        nrt_bal_sheet = g.Sum(n => n.balance)
    }
    ).ToList();
```

but I got this error.

> Error CS1061  'IGrouping<<anonymous type: DateTime date, string
> nrt_acc, string company_name>, nrt_bal_sheet>' does not contain a
> definition for 'date' and no extension method 'date' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: DateTime date, string
> nrt_acc, string company_name>, nrt_bal_sheet>' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me correct my linq query brothers.

Comment: Please add LINQ provider name and version (EF, NHibernate, etc.).

Comment: Try: "orderby g.key.date"

Comment: Tried it but error returns 
`Error CS1061 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: DateTime date, string nrt_acc, string company_name>, nrt_bal_sheet>' does not contain a definition for 'key' and no extension method 'key' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: DateTime date, string nrt_acc, string company_name>, nrt_bal_sheet>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
@TN

Answer (score 0):

As someone already indicated your Linq provider is important in this discussion. I.e. I tried this with Linq to Object and it works just fine as you can see from my LinqPad output screenshot. One option you have is to get the data, then do a `.ToList()` which will load your data in memory, then proceed with the rest of he Linq query so it will execute as Linq to Object. The bad side is that it will pull all the data from the datastore in memory.

[image: LinqPad query]